# Why does coffeescript require parentheses here?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

Look at the following snippets:

```coffee
if a
  return

if a b
  return

if (a b)
  return

if a(b)
  return

if a((b) -> c)
  return

if (a (b) -> c)
  return

if a (b) -> c
  return
```

The last one won't compile and it will produce a misleading error message, `unexpected if`.
I would expect it to produce the same output as the previous two.

Why is it not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

In the last example there is an ambiguity whether the return is part of the function, or of the if statement. If it's interpreted as part of the function, then it would be a syntax error as there is no body for the if statement.

```
if a (b) -> c
  return
```

Could be interpreted as you expected:

```
if (a (b) -> c)
  return
```

Or the indentation of the `return` is understood to be a continuation of the anonymous function:

```
if (a (b) -> c
  return)
```

In this case it gives an error as there is no body to go with the if statement.

I'm not certain, but I assume it chooses to place the `return` inside the function as this is the closest context, and it hasn't been explicitly closed (eg. with parenthesis).

As an alternative, It's safe enough to use the parenthesis as you have, as it will fail with a compile error rather than giving you unexpected behaviour that would be dificult to debug.

If all you are doing is `return`ing inside the if statement, you can use a trailing if:

```
return if a (b) -> c
```

Or execute the function first, then use the result in the if statement to make it more 
verbose:

```
isValid = a (b) -> c
return if isValid
```